# TimeZoneInfo -- translated standard name based on culture

Tags: c#, .net, localization, globalization

TimeZoneInfo.StandardName returns value only in English, is there a way I can get the translated name based on set culture?

Thx.

Comment: The short answer is: no way. It is localized on localized Windows. Period. As Peter suggested take a look at DisplayName to see if this is what could work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TimeZoneInfo are pulled from the registry...

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones

So its OS Language Dependent.

Changing the culture will have no effect in the Time Zone DisplayName. Of course, you can leverage resource files to achieve the desired affect.

Answer (score 1):

How about to create some class like "TimeZoneInfoExtension" which will have static method named like `ToLocalizedString`:

```
public static class TimeZoneInfoExtensions
{
    public static string ToLocalizedString(this TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        switch (timeZone.Id)
        {
            case "Dateline Standard Time":
                return i18n.DatelineStandardTime;

            case "UTC-11":
                return i18n.UTC11;

            case "Hawaiian Standard Time":
                return i18n.HawaiianStandardTime;

            case "Alaskan Standard Time":
                return i18n.AlaskanStandardTime;

            ....

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `i18n` is a class with resources. And yes, you have to fill translations manualy. But I just used something like this in different system languages to generate translations:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[ +-]");
foreach (var timeZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine("  <data name=\"{0}\" xml:space=\"preserve\">", rgx.Replace(timeZone.Id, string.Empty));
    Console.WriteLine("    <value>{0}</value>", timeZone.DisplayName);
    Console.WriteLine("  </data>");
}
```

And then you can get use it depending on your CurrentCulture like so:

```
foreach (var timeZoneInfo in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.ToLocalizedString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible because it is getting the information from the registry: `@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones"`

Answer (score -1):

You can get the localized name by using `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.displayname.aspx

Comment: This is wrong, because for english culture i get "Prague" which ok, but for culture Czech  i get same "Prague" but for czech localization it must be "Praha".

Comment: This link states: "Remarks - The display name is localized based on the culture installed with the Windows operating system."